# Is there a way to show partial class name in the testrunner for resharper?

Tags: resharper

I have created a set of tests that I have grouped together by using a partial class. Is there a way to get the partial name to show up in the test runner? What I have is something like

File 1:

```
 public partial class MyWrapperClass
 {
     [TestClass]
     public class This_is_a_descriptive_scenario { 
          [TestMethod]
          public void This_is_a_descriptive_scenario_outcome() { ... }
     }
 }
```

File 2:

```
 public partial class MyWrapperClass
 {
     [TestClass]
     public class This_is_a_descriptive_scenario2 { 
          [TestMethod]
          public void This_is_a_descriptive_scenario2_outcome() { ... }
     }
 }
```

When running tests like that in the builtin test runner in Visual studio I can see the result as: MyWrapperClass+This_is_a_descriptive_test, if I have added the class column to the test result. But when you run the test in resharper's testrunne they are grouped by project and/or namespace and the class name, but I can't see that the tests are part of a partial class anywhere. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is supported. Although it might be possible to extend it. I can point you in the right direction if you're willing to go down that path.

The easiest solution would be to use namespaces for grouping instead of partial classes.

Hope this helps

Miguel

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Maybe I must just satisfy with namespace. However, it would be nice if they supported partial classes so you can choose yourself.

Comment: The R# guys are really active and the best way to send a request for a new feature is via [YouTrack](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+Issue+Tracker). If you do, please post the link here so others can vote.

Answer (score 0):

The name of a partial class is the same in either file...  No, there's nothing that currently groups tests by test file name.

Comment: It only groups by namespace and the actual class containing the tests. I would like it to group them by partial class if it exists one.

Comment: But the partial class is the actual class.  I.e. if I have two class files for "MyClass" it's still only going to show "MyClass".  what you want is to group by file; that's the only differentiation of parts of a partial class..

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my example. If you look at it again you'll see that I have one partial class that is wrapping several inner classes that are the actual test classes.